# error exporting griddata to MS excel from Asp.net webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

I have use Asp.net webform c#.When exporting grid data to excel using the, I receive the following error message
"the file formate and extension of Mode of transport.xls don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe. unless you trust its source, don't open it. do you want to open it anyway"

The data appears fine once you click "Yes".

code:

```
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gvmodeoftransport.AllowPaging = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < gvmodeoftransport.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        gvmodeoftransport.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#df5015");
    }
    gvmodeoftransport.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```